# This operation cannot be performed because the specified virtual disk could not be found

Tags: virtual-machine, xen

Error: Starting VM on XenServer after migration(export and then import)
This operation cannot be performed because the specified virtual disk could not be found.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Basically when we export the vm and then import to other xenserver, sometime found the above issue.
If you go to the vm console tab using xencenter you can see the DVD drive is blank, you should have to empty that by clicking on eject.

via xe command:
xe vm-cd-list uuid={vmUUID} | grep "empty" | awk '{print $4}

if it returns false (it means the DVD drive is not empty) then run this command:

xe vm-cd-eject uuid={vmUUID}

Comment: I had this same issue on my Windows Server VM after updating XenServer from 6.2 to 6.5. Selecting <empty> in the DVD dropdown in XenCenter (I'm assuming this is identical to clicking "eject") fixed the issue.